# Is there an easy way in Java to filter for characters within a unicode version (3.2)?

Tags: java, unicode

I have a registration process in Java. I want to make sure the names used are all within unicode 3.2. This unicode requirement is for another part of my system which is not in java.

Does Java have a easy way to validate a string for unicode versions? I can't seem to find anything from some cursory checks.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would read this [UCD](http://www.unicode.org/Public/3.2-Update/UnicodeData-3.2.0.txt) file and build a BitSet from the first column. This would be fast way to test each code point in a String.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping Java had a library to handle this, but apparently it doesn't. We ended up using the linked UCD page, so this was helpful.

Comment: Java doesn't appear to be aware of different versions of Unicode.